# How to represent an unknown/blank word from a transcription in spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing, spacy

I am dealing with text from audio transcripts, and there are some unknown words. There are markers for each unknown word (e.g. "He unknown to the store"). I'm looking for the best way to represent the "unknown" word so as to mess up spacy's sentence dependency parsing the least.

What is the best replacement for  to increase odds that spacy's sentence dependency parser works the best across the widest range of sentences? Is a space/' ' or a '___' or a '...' or does it not matter? There is no structure to when/where the \ occur.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the words are unknown, it is best to simply remove them and truncate the extra space. If the unknown words/markers are not included in spacy vocabulary, they will anyway mess up dependency parsing, same goes for replacing them with special characters.

```
He / to the store
```

outputs:

```
He ROOT
/ punct
to prep
the det
store pobj
```

Whereas,

```
He to the store
```

outputs:

```
He ROOT
to prep
the det
store pobj
```

If you remove them, then basically you get a dependency parse that is correct for the rest of the transcription.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !